# how to plot bar gaps in pandas dataframe with timedelta and timestamp

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib, time-series, timespan

Given a timestamped df with timedelta showing time covered such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_timedelta(['00:45:00','01:00:00','00:30:00']).rename('span'), 
    index=pd.to_datetime(['2019-09-19 18:00','2019-09-19 19:00','2019-09-19 21:00']).rename('ts'))

#                         span
# ts                          
# 2019-09-19 18:00:00 00:45:00
# 2019-09-19 19:00:00 01:00:00
# 2019-09-19 21:00:00 00:30:00
```

How can I plot a bar graph showing drop outs every 15 minutes?   What I want is a bar graph that will show 0 or 1 on the Y axis with a 1 for each 15 minute segment in the time periods covered above, and a 0 for all the 15 minute segments not covered.

Per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23543909/plotting-pandas-timedelta) I tried:

```
df['span'].astype('timedelta64[m]').plot.bar()
```

However this plots each timespan vertically, and does not show that the whole hour of 2019-09-19 20:00 is missing.

[image: vertical_timegap_plot].

I tried

```
df['span'].astype('timedelta64[m]').plot()
```

It plots the following which is not very useful.

[image]

I also tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851731/plotting-from-a-pandas-dataframe-with-a-timedelta-index) to no avail.

## Update

Based on lostCode's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58020345) I was able to further modify the DataFrame as follows:

```
def isvalid(period):
    for ndx, row in df.iterrows():
        if (period.start_time >= ndx) and (period.start_time < row.end):
            return 1
    return 0
df['end']= df.index + df.span
ds = pd.period_range(df.index.min(), df.end.max(), freq='15T')
df_valid = pd.DataFrame(ds.map(isvalid).rename('valid'), index=ds.rename('period'))
```

Is there a better, more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to create a new DataFrame to 
to verify the existence of time spaces. To check use [DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
import numpy as np
check=df.resample('H')['span'].sum().reset_index()
d=df.reset_index('ts').sort_values('ts')
check['valid']=np.where(check['ts'].isin(d['ts']),1,0)
check.set_index('ts')['valid'].plot(kind='bar',figsize=(10,10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Yes that works per hour.  How can we add to it to resample every 15 minutes or every minute to show the dropout from 18:45:00 to 19:00:00?